# drop repository fails on file error

Tags: graphdb

Context: GraphDB 7.1.0

Using the `openrdf-console`, when requesting to drop a repository:

```
drop myrepo .
```

I get an error/exception:

```
[ERROR] 2016-09-13 09:44:32,369 [repositories/myrepo | o.o.h.s.ProtocolExceptionResolver] Error while handling request (500)
org.openrdf.http.server.ServerHTTPException: org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException: Unable to clean up resources for removed repository myrepo

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file/nas/install/graphdb/graphdb-se-7.1.0/graphdb-se-7.1.0/data/repositories/myrepo/storage/.nfs000000016e3e49b200000006
```

Any further attempt to drop the repo again or to add anything to it then fails on the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently GraphDB tries to delete the repository directory without closing the file descriptors pointing to files in this directory.

In my case, the data directory is potentially big and lies on a NAS which is attached through NFS.
When asked to delete an opened file, a temporary `.nfs000XXX`is created, and it stops the remove directory command.

A workaround is to stop GraphDB, delete the repository's directory by hand and restart GraphDB.